# PrintScreen key not registering in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, i3

I'm using Arch Linux with **i3 as my wm and running an x server.**
All my keys work but printscreen key doesn't even register.

I tried `xbindkeys -k` which seems to work for all keys except Print.

My keyboard is fine, because I have a dual boot with win10 where printscreen works flawlessly.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case not even `xbindkeys` or `xev` registered Print.
Solved it.

```
xmodmap -pk | grep Print

    107     0xff61 (Print)  0xff15 (Sys_Req)    0xff61 (Print)  0xff15 (Sys_Req)    
    218     0xff61 (Print)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0xff61 (Print)here
```

Yours should look like this. If it doesn't,

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 218 = Sys_Req"
```

So that only one key is mapped to Print.